# Know of a good page load progressbar for my ASP.net application?

Tags: asp.net, progress-bar, pageload

Just wondering if anyone has seen any usable progress bar for C# .net apps.  My app takes about 20-60 secs to load and I would love to show users a progress bar while they wait.  I saw [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETAJAXPageLoader.aspx) but the sample site doesn't seem to work which doesn't inspire confidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [AJAX UpdateProgress control](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updateprogress-control/).

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" id="PageUpdateProgress">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            Loading...
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="Panel">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" id="UpdateButton" onclick="UpdateButton_Click" text="Update" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If you want animation, all you need to do is pop an animated .gif into the 'ProgressTemplate'.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into this blog post - seems like a good way to do it. I haven't tested it myself...

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/05/aspnet_ajax_progress_bar_contr.html

Comment: Looks like that bar is used after the app has loaded to notify users during long trips to the server.  I need a bar to show as a splash screen while the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

In aspx page you need to write this,I have added certain CSS class which you yourself need to define, functinality wise this code will help you

```
<asp:Panel ID="ProgressIndicatorPanel" runat="server" Style="display: none" CssClass="modalPopup">
        <div id="ProgressDiv" class="progressStyle">
            <ul class="ProgressStyleTable" style="list-style:none;height:60px">
                <li style="position:static;float:left;margin-top:0.5em;margin-left:0.5em">
                    <asp:Image ID="ProgressImage" runat="server" SkinID="ProgressImage" />
                </li>
                <li style="position:static;float:left;margin-top:0.5em;margin-left:0.5em;margin-right:0.5em">
                    <span id="ProgressTextTableCell"> Loading, please wait... </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Define a function say ProgressIndicator as follows

```
var ProgressIndicator = function (progPrefix) {
    var divId = 'ProgressDiv';
    var textId = 'ProgressTextTableCell';
    var progressCss = "progressStyle";

    if (progPrefix != null) {
        divId = progPrefix + divId;
        textId = progPrefix + textId;
    }

    this.Start = function (textString) {
        if (textString) {
            $('#' + textId).text(textString);
        }
        else {
            $('#' + textId).text('Loading, please wait...');
        }
        this.Center();
        //$('#' + divId).show();
        var modalPopupBehavior = $find('ProgressModalPopupBehaviour');
        if (modalPopupBehavior != null) modalPopupBehavior.show();
    }

    this.Center = function () {
        var viewportWidth = jQuery(window).width();
        var viewportHeight = jQuery(window).height();
        var progressDiv = $("#" + divId);
        var elWidth = progressDiv.width();
        var elHeight = progressDiv.height();
        progressDiv.css({ top: ((viewportHeight / 2) - (elHeight / 2)) + $(window).scrollTop(),
            left: ((viewportWidth / 2) - (elWidth / 2)) + $(window).scrollLeft(), visibility: 'visible'
        });
    }

    this.Stop = function () {
        //$("#" + divId).hide();
        var modalPopupBehavior = $find('ProgressModalPopupBehaviour');
        if (modalPopupBehavior != null) modalPopupBehavior.hide();
    }
};
```

The example given conatins a Progress Indicator with  Modal ,i:e when progress Indicator is running it disables other operations to be performed on the screen.You can remove the Modal part if you doesnt need it .